# nth odd digit palindrome number

Tags: c++, palindrome

The following is the code of an nth even length palindrome, but i wanted to know the code for nth odd length palindrome.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
// Function to find nth even length Palindrome
string evenlength(string n)
{
    // string r to store resultant
    // palindrome. Initialize same as s
    string res = n;
 
    // In this loop string r stores
    // reverse of string s after the
    // string s in consecutive manner .
    for (int j = n.length() - 1; j >= 0; --j)
        res += n[j];
 
    return res;
}
 
// Driver code
int main()
{
    string n = "10";
   
    // Function call
    cout << evenlength(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would be the difference, in case of an odd length?

Comment: Could you give examples of an expected result? E.g. what is the correct answer for `10` or for `123`? The problem statement is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an odd length palindrome (i.e. `101` for an input of `10` or `1234321` for an input of `1234`), you might be able to replace the for loop with:

```
    for (int j = static_cast<int>(n.size()) - 2; j >= 0; --j)
        res += n[j];
```

(note `n.length() - 2` rather than `n.length() - 1`)

This will skip the last character when adding the reversed version so that the last digit only shows up once.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to take input as a string and return a string, you can also make a new variable that is a sub string of input(ignoring last digit),reverse it and concat and return.

```
    string Oddlength(string a)
    {
    string b;
    b=a.substr(0,a.size()-1);
    reverse(b.begin(),b.end());
    a+=b;
    return a;
    }
```

This works because the nth(n>10) odd digit palindrome number is just the number concat with the reverse of the number ignoring the last digit. While for (n<10), its the number itself.

So the 120th odd digit palindrome number is "120"+ "21"="12021".

1200th odd digit palindrome number is "1200" + "021"="1200021".